# Defining a Color using another

Tags: color

I know how to define a color using `\definecolor` with literals to describe the color. How can I define a color using an already defined color? In other words: How can I make a color accessible under multiple names?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This can be simply done using 
`\colorlet{mycolor}{someothercolor}` from the `xcolor` package. Here `someothercolor` can be any other color name or a color mix like
`colora!<number>!colorb`.

You should note that this copies the current color definition. If `someothercolor` is changed afterwards (e.g. using another `\colorlet`) `mycolor` will not change.