# Use red!50!blue with \definecolor

Tags: color

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Defining a Color using another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41980/defining-a-color-using-another)

How can one define a new color using the mix of other colors like `red!50!blue`. I can us this as an arguement of `\color` but not with `\defincolor` …

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{mix}{named}{red!50!blue}

\begin{document}
    \color{red!50!blue} works
    \color{mix} doesn't work
\end{document}
```

I guess it’s a problem with the pseudo-modell `named` since `red!50!blue` is not a single color name. But is there a color-modell accepting mixed colors to define a new one?

Comment: I found http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41980/4918 which seems to be  a duplicate. It’s shows a way using `\colorlet` but I still wonder if there’ll be a way using `\defincolor`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `\colorlet`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{mix}{red!50!blue}

\begin{document}
    \color{red!50!blue} works
    \color{mix} work as well
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, it's a duplicate.... "sorry for answering"