# Maroon faded effect

Tags: color

how can i made a faded version of this maroon? i want to get the same result of the classic thesis halfgray but in maroon version. i would to have a faded effect as if it is in transparency. Like this effect but for the maroon color:

---

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document} 
\color{Maroon} Hallo world!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `\color{Maroon!50} Hallo world!` do what you want? It mixes Maroon with equal parts white. You can mix other color combinations using `<color1>!<percentage>!<color2>`.

Comment: @Jake i think that halfgray in classicthesis is defined by \definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55} how can i made a maroon version of it?

Comment: i have try this `\definecolor{halfmaroon}{Maroon}{0.55}` but i get error...

Comment: The `gray` in the `\definecolor` refers to a *Colour Model* and explains how the `0.55` is to be interpreted.  To repeat the definition for maroon, you would have to look up the model used to define the maroon colour and repeat it with the appropriate adjustments.  It'll be something like `\definecolor{Maroon}{RGB}{.2,.3,.4}` (I may have the syntax wrong).  Or you could use the easier method that Jake outlines to define halfmaroon in terms of the existing colour.

Answer (score 5):

`\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}` refers to the colour `0.55` in the `gray` colour model, which is black mixed with 55% white. To define a new colour `halfmaroon` that consists of Maroon mixed with 55% white, you could use `\colorlet{halfmaroon}{Maroon!45!White}` (see [Defining a Color using another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41980/defining-a-color-using-another)). However, this colour is much lighter than the `halfgray` in `classicthesis`, so you'll have to experiment a bit to get an appropriate colour.