# Shades of colors

Tags: color

I have defined a new color with `\definecolor{MyBlue}{rgb}{0.25,0.5,0.75}`. Is it possible to define now "derivatives" of this in term of shades? I would like to use the same color in three different shades. It is possible to do this with grey by default, but can I define one mu own? Like

```
\definecolor{NextBlue}{MuBlue}{0.75}
```

I use the `xcolor` package.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

According to the answer at [Defining a Color using another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41980/defining-a-color-using-another), the `\colorlet` macro is what you should use to define the new color in terms of old ones.  Then you can specify shade variations on the new color.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{NextBlue}{red!25!green!50!blue!75}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{NextBlue}{Test}
\colorbox{NextBlue!20}{Test}
\colorbox{NextBlue!40}{Test}
\end{document}
```

[image: Image for test sample 1]

Or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{MyBlue}{rgb}{0.25,0.5,0.75}
\colorlet{NextBlue}{MyBlue!20}
\colorlet{SecondBlue}{MyBlue!40}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{MyBlue}{Test}
\colorbox{NextBlue}{Test}
\colorbox{SecondBlue}{Test}
\end{document}
```

[image: Image for test sample 2]

With shades between MyBlue and gray:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{MyBlue}{rgb}{0.25,0.5,0.75}
\colorlet{NextBlue}{MyBlue!60!gray}
\colorlet{SecondBlue}{MyBlue!30!gray}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{MyBlue}{Test}
\colorbox{NextBlue}{Test}
\colorbox{SecondBlue}{Test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, shades between two defined colors, `Myblue` and `Mygray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{Myblue}{rgb}{0.25,0.5,0.75}
\definecolor{Mygray}{rgb}{0.75,0.75,0.75}
\colorlet{NextBlue}{Myblue!66!Mygray}
\colorlet{SecondBlue}{Myblue!33!Mygray}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{Myblue}{Myblue}
\colorbox{NextBlue}{66\%Myblue34\%Mygray}
\colorbox{SecondBlue}{33\%Myblue67\%Mygray}
\colorbox{Mygray}{Mygray}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @HarishKumar Thank you for expanding the scope of the answer!

Comment: To all the editors who have improved my answer, thank you.

Comment: hove anyone noted the difference of the result of a color defined by \colorlet{NextBlue}{red!25!green!50!blue!75}  with the color dined by \definecolor{MyBlue}{rgb}{0.25,0.5,0.75}

Comment: @OmidGhayour Whereas `\definecolor{MyBlue}{rgb}{0.25,0.5,0.75}` specifies the actual quantities of red, green, and blue, there is a more complex way to interpret `red!25!green!50!blue!75`, something along the lines of 25% red; of the remaining 75%, make half of it (37.5%) green, of the remaining 37.5%, make 75% of that (28.125%) blue.  The residual 9.375% is white.  I could be wrong on the particulars, but the meanings of the two syntaxes are not the same.