# How does LaTeX specify colors?

Tags: color, tcolorbox

How does LaTeX specify colors? For example, take the following excerpt from p. 28 of [the `tcolorbox` package's user manual](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf).

[image: tcolorbox color specs]

What does `red!75!black` mean?

I would appreciate the most general answer, for instance, I believe I've seen somewhere in the manual a color specification consisting of four parts (as opposed to three parts used in the example above), so I would appreciate it if the answer covered that case too as well as any other case that may arise.

If the color specifications are described in the manual or somewhere else, a simple page number or hyperlink is fine by me.

Comment: The percentage and the gradation of the two colors.

Comment: I recommend reading `xcolor` manual which `tcolorbox` uses. That is the master package for managing the color in LaTeX

Comment: See: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors "If you loaded the `xcolor` package, you can define colors upon previously defined ones.

The first specifies 20 percent blue and 80 percent white; the second is a mixture of 20 percent blue and 80 percent black; and the last one is a mixture of (20*0.3) percent blue, ((100-20)*0.3) percent black and (100-30) percent green.
[3 examples:]
\color{blue!20}
\color{blue!20!black}
\color{blue!20!black!30!green}
"

Comment: [Chapter 1.1 Purpose of this package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf) on page 4 (the xcolor
package)

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180453/shades-of-colors

Comment: The wikibook is **not** a recommended source, unfortunately. @Bobyandbob

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A general answer to your question would be to study the [`xcolor`](//ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) [documentation](//mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf). The package allows for all sorts of colour *mixing*.

Specific to your inquiry, read the introductory section **1.1 Purpose of this package** (p 4):

> How does a mixture of 40% green and 60% yellow look like?
>
> ```
> \color{green!40!yellow}
> ```

As such, `red!75!black` would be 75% red and 25% black. A darker red colour.