# How can one use macros to define colors?

Tags: pdftex, color, kvoptions

I want to write a package which may be loaded with key-value options that are meant to be used to define colors by means of the package `xcolor`. The package `kvoptions` is to be used to facilitate the processing of the key-value options. Package `kvoptions` defines macros to hold values of options. I have difficulties in figuring out how to use macros in color definition. The `LaTeX2e` code given below is a crude attempt to use the macro `fcbcolorname` to define the color `fcbcolor`. The code does not compile. The `pdflatex` compiler flags the second line as `an undefined control sequence`.

```
\def\fcbcolorname{blue!50!red}
\xglobal\colorlet{fcbcolor}{\fcbcolorname}
```

I acknowledge the naivety in my approach to solving the problem. Does someone know of a solution to my problem? I'll appreciate any help towards solving the problem.

Following comments by `@egreg` I have discovered that the following MWE works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\fcbcolorname{blue!50!red}
\xglobal\colorlet{fcbcolor}{\fcbcolorname}
\begin{document}
\color{fcbcolor} What is the color of this line of text?
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code a MWE.

Comment: Works for me. What's the undefined control sequence?

Comment: Thanks @TeXnician and @egreg. I have established that the given code works, thanks to the prompting by @egreg. I had made a fundamental mistake: I did not use the code `\color{fcbcolor}` at the point where I needed to invoke the color command. My re-edited post gives MWE.

Comment: A working code does not clarify your question, I'm afraid.

Comment: Related?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180453/shades-of-colors

Comment: Thanks once more `@egreg`. The MWE captures the gist of what I had in mind about the specification of a globally declared color using key-value option. Suppose I load my package as follows: `\usepackage[objectcolor=blue!50]{mypackage}`. The processing of the option using package `kvoptions` would result in the value of the option being held in the macro `\mypackage@objectcolor`. My worry was whether or not I could use the macro in the color definition, e.g. `\xglobal\colorlet{Obcolor}{\mypackage@objectcolor}`. Thanks to your earlier contribution, I solved the problem.