# How to use (exclamation mark) color mix with \definecolor?

Tags: color

I need to use

```
blue!50
```

with

```
\definecolor
```

but they do not seem to be compatible. A workaround would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you trying to combine them? Please provide code for a small document we can use to reproduce the problem and a statement of the problem. Probably you are looking for `\colorlet`.

Comment: Related/duplicate?: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180453/shades-of-colors

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> `xcolor` also feature a handy command to define colors from color
>   mixes:
>
> ```
> \colorlet{notgreen}{blue!50!yellow}
> ```

Copied directly from [Wikibooks -
LaTeX/Colors](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors) section "Defining new colors", searched by writing `define color latex` in my browser.

Comment: I ran `xcolor definecolor with exclamation marks` through the search box and landed on this page, where I found the answer to my question much quicklier than on the Wikibooks site. We all get around somehow, it seems.