# Defining main colors and sub colors

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I am using the packages `xcolor` and `tikz`.

I have defined my own color in `rgb` which name is `MyColor1`. I am using multiple times in Ti*k*Z `MyColor1!50!white` and I want to define it as `Mycolor2` so that if I want to modify the percentage of white I don't have to do it manually each time I am using `MyColor1!50!white`. I don't know if I can do it in `xcolor` or in Ti*k*Z.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: How about `\colorlet{Mycolor2}{MyColor1!50!white}`?

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Should I remove the question?

Comment: No, please don't remove it. Duplicates are actually something good - they make it easier for future users to search for a solution

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180453/shades-of-colors