# Define local variable for global color highlight?

Tags: color, lyx, variable

let say I have a document with several places where I'm highlighting with color, how can I create a 'synonim' or 'variable' that I can change in a single place of the document instead of going through each and one of the \color{something} that I have.

```
&= {3}\,·\color{Chartreuse4}\int_{-\frac{3}{2}}^{1} x^2\mathop{dx}
&&- \color{Chartreuse4}\int_{-\frac{3}{2}}^{1}x^2\mathop{dx}+ \int_{-\frac{3}{2}}^{1}x\mathop{dx}
&&&\color{Chartreuse4}\text{\{Integral $x^n = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$\}}
```

Say I have that, how can I declare a variable that says:
"color_variable=Chartreuse4" and then I can just do:

```
&= {3}\,·\color{color_variable}\int_{-\frac{3}{2}}^{1} x^2\mathop{dx}
&&- \color{color_variable}\int_{-\frac{3}{2}}^{1}x^2\mathop{dx}+ \int_{-\frac{3}{2}}^{1}x\mathop{dx}
&&&\color{color_variable}\text{\{Integral $x^n = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$\}}
```

and simply change the evaluation of color_variable to red, green, blue, or whatever.
Similar to CSS documents where all items that are from the same "class" change color when I change the property.
Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this question could help, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180453/shades-of-colors.  The key is `\colorlet`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @StevenB.Segletes I tried that and it worked.

Comment: I am voting to mark this question as a duplicate, since you indicate the referenced question solved your issue.

Comment: If you're doing that I don't know if I can change it, make sure to link to this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41980/defining-a-color-using-another 
As it's the good answer right to the point.

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks to this previous answer:
[Defining a Color using another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41980/defining-a-color-using-another)
And this:
[Shades of colors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180453/shades-of-colors)
We can use the

```
\colorlet{mycolor}{alreadydefinedcolor}
```

to make it happen.

On LyX, you have to be sure to declare it **outside** any `\begin` statement.