# Define the color command

Tags: color

How can I bind this to another command?

`\definecolor{thisismycolor}{rgb}{0.012,0.11,0.5}`

**Normally:**

`\draw[color=thisismycolor]`

**But, I want this:**

`\draw[color=mycolor]`

So i want to connect `thisismycolor` and `mycolor`

**For example:**

`\newcommand{\mycolor}{\thisismycolor}` but dont work

**In summary:** When `\thisismycolor` changes as let the `\mycolor` change too.

Comment: It is unclear what you want. Perhaps you are looking for `\colorlet` from the xcolor package?

Comment: When I type `color=\mycolor` I want it to automatically give the top color. @plante

Comment: I edited the post @campa

Comment: `\colorlet{mycolor}{thisismycolor}`

Comment: Thank you @StevenB.Segletes

Comment: However, if you are speaking of `mycolor` changing when `thisismycolor` changes, perhaps you instead want `\newcommand\mycolor{thisismycolor}` and then use something like `\textcolor{\mycolor}{...}`.  That way, when `thisismycolor` changes, so will `\mycolor`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than a simple `\colorlet{newcolor}{existingcolor}`, which will allow a new color to be defined in terms of existing color(s) (see [Shades of colors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180453/shades-of-colors), [Defining a Color using another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41980/defining-a-color-using-another)), it seems the OP wants a shortcut for a long color name.  In particular the desire seems to be that, when the longcolorname changes, the shorthand will change with it.

If this is the case, then `\colorlet{newcolor}{existingcolor}` will not suffice, as the color known as `newcolor` will not revise itself when `existingcolor` gets subsequently updated.  Indeed, a `\colorlet` is a one-time assignment, but not a "linkage".  After the `\colorlet` is executed, a change in the specification of `existingcolor` will, by design, have no effect on the specification of `newcolor`.

In that case, use a shorthand macro to refer to the long name, in the manner of `\newcommand\mycolor{thisismycolor}`.  This way, you can refer to `\mycolor` whenever a color is called for, and it will take on the *current* value of `thisismycolor`.  The key here to understanding is that the color that is defined is `thisismycolor`.  The term `\mycolor` is not, itself, a color, but merely a macro that gets replaced with a color name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{thisismycolor}{red!80!cyan}
\newcommand\mycolor{thisismycolor}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{\mycolor}{A Test}

\colorlet{thisismycolor}{green!50!cyan}
\textcolor{\mycolor}{A Test}
\end{document}
```

[image]